# How to automate swipe gestures for iOS mobile app using iOS simulator in java?

Tags: java, ios, appium, mobile-application, swipe-gesture

1. I need to automate swipe gesture for both side(Right To Left and Left to Right) in  iOS mobile app.
2. I am using appium version 1.4.8 , iOS simulator 6 and platform version as 8.3.
3. I am writing test cases using java language.
4. I have tried with below coding for swipe gestures. But, the swipe action doesn't happens for me.

> ```
>  public void swipeLeftToRight(AppiumDriver driver) {
>      Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
>      int endx = (int) (size.width * 0.8);
>      int startx = (int) (size.width * 0.20);
>      int starty = size.height / 2;
>
>      driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, starty, 1000);
>  }
>
>  public void swipeRightToLeft(AppiumDriver driver) {
>      Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
>      int startx = (int) (size.width * 0.8);
>      int endx = (int) (size.width * 0.10);
>      int starty = size.height / 2;
>
>      driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, starty, 1000);
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use TouchAction class to perform this operation. Try this:

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver).longPress(longPress).moveTo().release();
action.perform();
```

Comment: longPress(longPress), in this line, (longPress) is a variable or web element.

Comment: webelement. Check here - http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/TouchAction.html

Answer (score 0):

For me below code worked for case "swipe from left to right on ios real device"
I think just changing the "direction" value as "left" will be enough for case "swipe
from right to left" 
P.s: If you are using webwiev application, then before applying below code, you should switch to native view
I hope it helps

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
 scrollObject.put("direction", "right");
 WebElement element = ((IOSDriver) device.getDriver()).findElementById("id");
 scrollObject.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId());
 js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", scrollObject);
```